# Markdown breaks fluidPage column widths in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

As per title. To illustrate:

```
md = "# Lorem ipsum

1. dolor sit amet, amet ut integer vitae, justo pretium sed praesent, velit vitae proin molestie metus nec. A mi id quisque libero, in sed urna non etiam iaculis id, purus cum sit et. Maecenas purus sit rhoncus fringilla velit, etiam et justo risus pharetra, leo convallis ut platea, turpis tellus urna sed, leo scelerisque velit nam urna. Felis tincidunt fringilla, suspendisse molestie dui, phasellus aliquam nec adipiscing enim fusce metus, vulputate dictumst etiam est a. Rhoncus ut, netus aenean rutrum vehicula ipsum, maecenas nec ut mauris."

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             selectInput('countries', 'countries', state.name, "country")
      ),
      column(9,
             plotOutput('plot'),
             uiOutput('markdown')
      )
    )
  ),

  function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(rnorm(100))
    })
    output$markdown <- renderUI({
      HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(text = md))
    })
  },
  options = list(launch.browser=T)
)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Compare that to rendering text:

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             selectInput('countries', 'countries', state.name, "country")
      ),
      column(9,
             plotOutput('plot'),
             textOutput('txt')
      )
    )
  ),

  function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(rnorm(100))
    })
    output$txt <- renderText(md)
  },
  options = list(launch.browser=T)
)
```

This is how it should look:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the option `fragment.only = TRUE` in the call to `markdownToHTML()` :

```
 output$markdown <- renderUI({
      HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(text = md,
                                    fragment.only = TRUE))
    })
```

After adding this, the app looks exactly like your second example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Joris